# SwiftUI ObservedObject not updating

Tags: swiftui

This is the code I have:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var searchText: String = ""
    @State private var editMode = EditMode.inactive
    
    
    @ObservedObject var contentVM = ContentVM()
        
    var body: some View {
        if self.contentVM.loading {
            Text("Loading")
        } else {
            Text("Not loading")
        }
    }    
}

final class ContentVM: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var loading = true
    
    private var timer: Timer = Timer()
    
    init() {
        
        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: false) { timer in
            self.loading = false
            print("Not loading any more")
        }
        
    }
}
```

I can see that the console prints out "Not loading any more" correctly, but the content view does not update to show the "Not loading" text.

Edit: It seems objectWillChange.send() does the job, but I feel like a primitive such as a boolean should automatically notify once updated. Am I incorrect?

Comment: Works fine with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

Comment: Are you using the same instance of `ContentVM` throughout the application?

Comment: Yes, and I am on XCode 12.2.